# Web Request Utility

Tags: c#, json

Our company consumes a lot of telemetered data from sensors which we consume via an API.  So I wrote a method to consume them a bit easier for internal applications.  I didn't add a generic to the method, mostly because JSON.NET didn't always build the object correctly.  I'd like to remedy that in the future, but as it stands:

```
public object DownloadFromApi(string url)
{
    if (WebRequest.Create(url) is HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                if (stream != null)
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                            ApplicationProvider.Log.Error(
                                    $"Failed Request with code of {response.StatusCode} at {url}");

                        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    }

            ApplicationProvider.Log.Fatal($"No response from {url}");
            throw new Exception($"No response from web server {url}");
        }

        catch (HttpRequestException exception)
        {
            ApplicationProvider.Log.Fatal($"An unhandled HTTP error has occurred.{Environment.NewLine}{exception.Message}");
            throw new Exception(exception.Message);
        }
    }

    ApplicationProvider.Log.Fatal($"Web request failed due to null value. {url}");
    throw new Exception($"A null parameter or response has occurred for {url}");
}
```

I wanted to catch the various issues that may be encountered while consuming, could I improve or do this better?

Comment: The `if/using/using/if/using/if` cascade is pretty scarry! C# is not python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have concerns with your lack of Braces for the if then using if then using chain.

because you didn't use curly braces it appears that you don't close the blocks and that the code will not compile.

My personal opinion is that you should use Braces here to make sure that you know what scope you are in, and for the developers after you to know what scope you are in.

---

You shouldn't wait until the end of the code to fail because of a null value passed in for the `url`.  you should check for that right out of the gate.

---

I also noticed that you used Var to declare your using object, for the Reader object but not for any of the other disposables, You should be consistent.  one way or the other.

here is how it would look if you changed the things I suggest.

```
public object DownloadFromApi(string url)
{
    if (url is null)
    {
        ApplicationProvider.Log.Fatal($"Web request failed due to null value. {url}");
        throw new Exception($"A null parameter or response has occurred for {url}");
    }

    if (WebRequest.Create(url) is HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        try
        {
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            ApplicationProvider.Log.Error(
                                    $"Failed Request with code of {response.StatusCode} at {url}");
                        }
                        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                }
            }
            ApplicationProvider.Log.Fatal($"No response from {url}");
            throw new Exception($"No response from web server {url}");
        }

        catch (HttpRequestException exception)
        {
            ApplicationProvider.Log.Fatal($"An unhandled HTTP error has occurred.{Environment.NewLine}{exception.Message}");
            throw new Exception(exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The brace comment I receive frequently, I personally find them redundant when the scope directly nest within another.  Does the above pattern matching actually work though you're casting from WebRequest to HttpWebRequest?  I declare var when the direct right hand corresponding clearly indicates type, otherwise I define.  Not sure if I'm alone for those two though.

Comment: I am not casting anything any differently than you did in your original code.  I only used `var` where it is possible to use it.

Comment: Ah, I apologize I didn't realize I did pattern matching.  Been one of those days.  The var approach though, should I not follow that practice?  If the right doesn't clearly indicate type I use the type, otherwise I use var.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you say this code is horrible and difficult to understand?

Comment: if the right side of the declaration isn't clear what type it is, you will get an error.  `response.GetResponseStream()` is a Stream, I know that the method `GetResponseStream` is going to return to me a `Stream`.  the line `var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse()` the part inside the Parenthesis is a cast, which is possible because the what is returned is castable to that.

Comment: I don't think that your code is hard to understand other than the lack of curly braces, because I accustomed to the Curly Braces.  although it is the first time I have seen `WebRequest.Create(url) is HttpWebRequest request`

Comment: I modified because for some reason I did put a var there, instead of type.  But you're correct, seems like a fair assessment.

Comment: @Greg, [I understand, we just have a rule about changing the question after you have received an answer.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/18427)

Comment: Oh, didn't know my apologies.  Thank you for your valuable feedback though.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of severe issues with your code so it won't work the way you think it would and you will also loose a lot of useful information.

---

> ```
> ApplicationProvider.Log.Fatal($"Web request failed due to null value. {url}");
> throw new Exception($"A null parameter or response has occurred for {url}");
> ```

These two lines will never be executed because the [`WebRequest.Create Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc(v=vs.110).aspx) will throw the

> ArgumentNullException if requestUriString is null.

This will happen before you can log it so you should validate the argument yourself with:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(url));
```

---

In order to reduce nesting you should use early returns. This means that you should negate the first condition:

```
if (!(WebRequest.Create(url) is HttpWebRequest request))
{
    ...
}
```

in other places however you can use positive conditions (which are preferable because they are easier to understand) to further reduce nesting like where you check the `stream`:

```
if (stream == null)
```

---

Your method only throws `Exception`s. This is always bad because the name of the exception is a very important information source for why it was thrown. If you don't want to reveal what really happened, or if you want to use a more generic exception the you should create your own type. But when you do it, don't leave the stack trace behind by not passing the previous exception as inner exception.

Without you providing more context, I find you code should optimally look like this:

- check the argument and throw early
- create a web-request and throw early if it wasn't what you'd expected
- try to get the stream an throw early if it's null
- if the `HttpRequestException` was thrown, log it and either rethrow with with simple `throw;` or throw you own exception passing the other one as parameter.

Example:

```
public object DownloadFromApi(string url)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(url));

    if (!(WebRequest.Create(url) is HttpWebRequest request))
    {
        ApplicationProvider.Log.Fatal($"Web request failed due to null value. {url}");
        throw new InvalidUrlException($"The provider url '{url}' is not a http-web-request url.");
    }

    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";

    try
    {
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (stream == null)
            {
                ApplicationProvider.Log.Fatal($"No response from {url}");
                throw new ResponseException($"No response from web server {url}");
            }

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(reader.ReadToEnd());                    
                }

                ApplicationProvider.Log.Error($"Failed Request with code of {response.StatusCode} at {url}");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException innerException)
    {
        ApplicationProvider.Log.Fatal($"An unhandled HTTP error has occurred.{Environment.NewLine}{exception.Message}");
        throw new DownloadException(innerException);
    }
}
```

It's just an example. You can of course use other exception type that suit your needs but remember to not use the `Exception`, it's not helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Tech, that would be helpful to negate to reduce nesting.

Comment: Your code technically has the "not all code paths return a value" issue though.

Comment: @Greg this is possible... it happens when you're unable to compile it, but I'm pretty sure you know how to fix it, after all it's just an example ;-] (I think I know where, below the `StatusCode` check...)

Comment: That is quite true, I found a solution to cater to the check.  Appreciate the assistance.